# Bayesian Spatial Prediction: What is f?

Tags: bayesian, spatial, spatio-temporal

I'm working my way through Gelfand, A.E. & Li Zhu, B.P.C. (2001).  On the change of support problem in spatio-temporal data.  Biostatistics, 2:1, 31-45.

I'm stuck at:
[image]

This is absolutely the first mention of f anywhere in the paper.  Can someone help me to identify it?

- Y = spatial process
- s = measured locations
- Beta, Theta = presumed
  coefficients for mean function and covariance function
- H = pairwise
  (?) covariance function <-- not too clear about that

Comment: Given that "$f$" clearly stands for at three very different things in its three appearances in equation (3), and both are conditional probability distributions, it would seem that this letter has been reserved by the authors generically to refer to any probability density function.  $H$ is defined in equation (2) *et seq.*

Comment: Thanks, but those three very different things aren't clear to me. The "Regardless ..." sentence made me think it was a conditional distribution.  So equation 3 says:

Comment: the new distribution of the Ys' is the area under (the pdf for Ys' times what? -- the original distribution of Ys?)  Am I conflating conditional distribution and probability density function?  This is all a little rusty and never mastered well to begin with.  Thank you for your explanation.